# Connection refused with Java restHighLevelClient

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, docker-compose, centos

I'm working on a Spring Boot App that makes a bulk insert from Oracle database to an Elasticsearch cluster hosted on a CentOS 7 server. When I use some HTTP client like Insomnia or Postman then cluster responses with status 200 OK, even CURL does not have problems to make a correct PUT request to server. Spring Boot app just can't establish the connection.

When I up the docker-compose on the same develop PC where Spring Boot App is running bulk inserts are OK, but just not on CentOS server.

I'm sure that SELinux and firewalld services was stopped in CentOS server. Ping to the server, external HTTP client request, CURL request, all of them return a correct response.

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2.2'
services:
  es01:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.1.0
    container_name: es01
    environment:
      - node.name=es01
      - discovery.seed_hosts=es02,es03,es04,es05
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=es01,es02,es03,es04,es05
      - cluster.name=docker-cluster
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms1024m -Xmx1024m"
      - http.host=0.0.0.0
      - transport.host=0.0.0.0
      - xpack.security.enabled=false
      - "http.cors.enabled=false"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - esdata01:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
      - 9300:9300
    networks:
      - esnet
  es02:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.1.0
    container_name: es02
    environment:
      - node.name=es02
      - discovery.seed_hosts=es01,es03,es04,es05
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=es01,es02,es03,es04,es05
      - cluster.name=docker-cluster
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms1024m -Xmx1024m"
      - http.host=0.0.0.0
      - transport.host=0.0.0.0
      - xpack.security.enabled=false
      - "http.cors.enabled=false"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - esdata02:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    networks:
      - esnet
  es03:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.1.0
    container_name: es03
    environment:
      - node.name=es03
      - discovery.seed_hosts=es01,es02,es04,es05
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=es01,es02,es03,es04,es05
      - cluster.name=docker-cluster
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms1024m -Xmx1024m"
      - http.host=0.0.0.0
      - transport.host=0.0.0.0
      - xpack.security.enabled=false
      - "http.cors.enabled=false"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - esdata03:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    networks:
      - esnet
  es04:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.1.0
    container_name: es04
    environment:
      - node.name=es04
      - discovery.seed_hosts=es01,es02,es03,es05
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=es01,es02,es03,es04,es05
      - cluster.name=docker-cluster
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms1024m -Xmx1024m"
      - http.host=0.0.0.0
      - transport.host=0.0.0.0
      - xpack.security.enabled=false
      - "http.cors.enabled=false"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - esdata04:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    networks:
      - esnet
  es05:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.1.0
    container_name: es05
    environment:
      - node.name=es05
      - discovery.seed_hosts=es01,es02,es03,es04
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=es01,es02,es03,es04,es05
      - cluster.name=docker-cluster
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms1024m -Xmx1024m"
      - http.host=0.0.0.0
      - transport.host=0.0.0.0
      - xpack.security.enabled=false
      - "http.cors.enabled=false"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - esdata05:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    networks:
      - esnet

volumes:
  esdata01:
    driver: local
  esdata02:
    driver: local
  esdata03:
    driver: local
  esdata04:
    driver: local
  esdata05:
    driver: local

networks:
  esnet:
```

Elasticsearch config

```java
package artifact.busquedas.config;

import org.apache.http.HttpHost;
import org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient;
import org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.AbstractFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class ElasticsearchConfig extends AbstractFactoryBean {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ElasticsearchConfig.class);

    @Value("${elasticsearch.host}")
    private String host;
    @Value("${elasticsearch.port}")
    private int port;
    @Value("${elasticsearch.cluster-name}")
    private String clusterName;
    private RestHighLevelClient restHighLevelClient;



    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        try {
            if (restHighLevelClient != null) {
                restHighLevelClient.close();
            }
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            LOG.error("Error closing ElasticSearch client: ", e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Class<RestHighLevelClient> getObjectType() {
        return RestHighLevelClient.class;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isSingleton() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public RestHighLevelClient createInstance() {
        return buildClient();
    }

    private RestHighLevelClient buildClient() {
        try {
            restHighLevelClient = new RestHighLevelClient(
                    RestClient.builder(
                            new HttpHost(host, port, "http")));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.error(e.getMessage());
        }
        return restHighLevelClient;
    }

}
```

Elasticsearch params on application.properties file

```
#Elasticsearch config
    elasticsearch.repositories.enabled=true
    elasticsearch.host=10.10.20.XX
    elasticsearch.port=9200
    elasticsearch.cluster-name=docker-cluster
```

Elasticsearch repository that makes the bulk insert

```java
public void bulkInsert(List<NacimientoElastic> nacimientos) {
      try {
        BulkRequest bulkRequest = new BulkRequest();
        for (int i = 0; i < nacimientos.size(); i++) {
              Map data = objectMapper.convertValue(nacimientos.get(i), Map.class);
              IndexRequest indexRequest = new IndexRequest(INDEX,TYPE,nacimientos.get(i).getId()).source(data);
              bulkRequest.add(indexRequest);
            }
          restHighLevelClient.bulk(bulkRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT).getTook());
          }

          } catch (IOException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
}
```

The Spring Boot App returns the following message:

```
 "java.net.ConnectException: Conexión rehusada
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.extractAndWrapCause(RestClient.java:804)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequest(RestClient.java:225)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequest(RestClient.java:212)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.internalPerformRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:1433)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:1403)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequestAndParseEntity(RestHighLevelClient.java:1373)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.bulk(RestHighLevelClient.java:477)
    at artifact.repositorio.RegistroRepositorioElastic.bulkInsert(RegistroRepositorioElastic.java:67)
    at artifact.repositorio.RegistroRepositorioElastic$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$9c045f6e.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688)
    at artifact.repositorio.RegistroRepositorioElastic$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$abc7eab.bulkInsert(<generated>)
    at artifact.busquedas.serviciosImp.NacimientosImplementacion.replicarOracleAElastic(NacimientosImplementacion.java:50)
    at artifact.busquedas.controladores.BusquedaControlador.replicarRegistroCivil(BusquedaControlador.java:33)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:892)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1039)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:897)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:200)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:836)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1747)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Conexión rehusada
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.DefaultConnectingIOReactor.processEvent(DefaultConnectingIOReactor.java:171)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.DefaultConnectingIOReactor.processEvents(DefaultConnectingIOReactor.java:145)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.execute(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:351)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.conn.PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager.execute(PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager.java:221)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.CloseableHttpAsyncClientBase$1.run(CloseableHttpAsyncClientBase.java:64)
    ... 1 more
"
```

Not sure if there are some CORS config in Elasticsearch cluster or something like that, but I'm guess it is disabled on the docker-compose.yml for all nodes.